# APA in-text citation: Citing multiple works from same first author, different multiple co-authors, and different years

Tags: citations, apa

For the APA 7th edition style, if I am citing multiple works led by the same first author, but have different multiple co-authors (two or more authors), and are published in different years, how should I cite them?

E.g., assume I am citing Alpha, Delta, Beta, & Lambda (2020) and Alpha, Beta, Gamma, & Lambda (2024) together.

Should the proper APA (7th ed.) in-text citation form be:

`(Alpha et al., 2024; Alpha et al., 2020)` | `Alpha et al. (2024) and Alpha et al. (2020)`

(note: I put "2024" before "2020" because the 2024 reference would appear alphabetically before the 2020 reference in the Reference list)

or

`(Alpha et al., 2020, 2024)` | `Alpha et al. (2020, 2024)`?

I read from online resources that if there are [multiple works by the same authors](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/multiple-works#:%7E:text=When%20citing%20multiple%20works%20parenthetically,order%2C%20separating%20them%20with%20semicolons.&text=Arrange%20two%20or%20more%20works,with%20dates%20in%20chronological%20order.), then the citation should take on the latter form (and be arranged by year of publication). Not all the authors in those two references are the same, but both citations will appear as "[first author] et al." in the standard in-text citation form if they are cited independently.

So should the citation form when they are cited together be like the former or the latter?

Answer (score 0):

Your authors are different, so use a semicolon.

`(Author(s), Year a, Year b)` means that two publications were written by the same author(s).

`(Author(s), Year a; Author(s), Year b)` means that two publications were written by different author(s).

You seem to be confused because the multipe authors in your examples shorten to the same *et al.*

But since
`Alpha, Delta, Beta, & Lambda` ≠ `Alpha, Beta, Gamma, & Lambda`,
therefore
`Alpha et al.`                 ≠ `Alpha et al.`                .

So don't `Alpha et al., 2020, 2024`, but `Alpha et al., 2024; Alpha et al., 2020`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Ben. The 7th edition APA manual did change on those rules for works by multiple authors. I've also read about the 7th edition's equivalent section 6.12 from a few reliable web sources about the APA 7th ed. (e.g., [Purdue OWL](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/in_text_citations_author_authors.html)). That rule is retained in the 7th ed. I was going to add it to my post; however, I decided it was not relevant because that rule of citing more authors' names only applies when the publication years are the same.

Comment: @LC-datascientist I misread your question. My mistake. I edited my answer.